# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 78543360 into shape (51135,4,32,32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, conv-neural-network, lstm

Following this tutorial from https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-rnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/

I’m trying to implement CNN-LSTM Network Model on my time series data.

```
verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 25, 64
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = 
X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], y_train.shape[1]
# reshape data into time steps of sub-sequences
n_steps, n_length = 4, 32
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], n_steps, 
n_length, n_features))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], n_steps, 
n_length, n_features))
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, 
kernel_size=3, activation='relu'), input_shape= 
(None,n_length,n_features)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, 
kernel_size=3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, 
batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
```

Here are Shapes before using reshape:

```
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, 
y_test.shape)
(51135, 128, 12) (51135, 1) (21915, 128, 12) (21915, 1)
```

Here is the section of the code I am having an error with:
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 78543360 into shape (51135, 4,32,32)`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have access to your data so I created dummy np.zero arrays for the data with the dimensions you specified. Ran it to see what was happening to the dimensions. Did not encounter the error you describe. Code I used is below. Runs and trains  so the dimensions appear to be correct.

```
X_train=np.zeros((51135, 128, 12))
y_train=np.zeros((51135, 1))
X_test=np.zeros((21915, 128, 12))
y_test=np.zeros((21915, 1))
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape,y_test.shape)
verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 25, 64
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], y_train.shape[1]
print(n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs)
# reshape data into time steps of sub-sequences
n_steps, n_length = 4, 32
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], n_steps, n_length, n_features))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], n_steps,n_length, n_features))
print (X_train.shape, X_test.shape)
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, 
kernel_size=3, activation='relu'), input_shape= 
(None,n_length,n_features)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, 
kernel_size=3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

Here is the data that gets printed out. Of course with all zeros training data is meaningless but the dimensions are right for model.fit to execute

```
(51135, 128, 12) (51135, 1) (21915, 128, 12) (21915, 1)
128 12 1
(51135, 4, 32, 12) (21915, 4, 32, 12)
Epoch 1/25
799/799 [==============================] - 9s 11ms/step - loss: 0.6051 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2/25
799/799 [==============================] - 5s 6ms/step - loss: 0.3479 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reshape X_train to (51135, 4,32,32). It is impossible because X_train shape is (51135, 128, 12). 51135 x 128 x 12 != 51135 x 4 x 32 x 32

Comment: Hi @Andrey, Thanks for you answer. Can you suggest me what should I do to fix this error?

Comment: @Alanda What is X_train ? Why does it have such shape ?